# What controls initial scale?

Tags: css, responsive-design, viewport

Does anybody know what CSS rule, if any, controls the initial-scale property? What is 100%? I set a min-width of my site to 445px and I would like the site to be viewed at this size when initially loading the page, It currently shows a bit zoomed in and needs to be "zoomed out" before fitting on the screen.

I am using this viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

Comment: Well, there's a meta tag for markup, but I don't know of any CSS rules to control it.

Comment: Yes, I am using the markup `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>`

Comment: @JuanRangel Can you provide a link or more code samples? What browsers are zooming in, just Mobile Safari?